# Hudson build fails with Fatal Error (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$HeapDump )

Tags: maven-2, continuous-integration, hudson

Hopefully, someone can point out what maybe the issue causing the Fatal Error I receive when doing a Maven build using Hudson.

I just installed an instance of Hudson in Tomcat on a Windows XP box in a test environment.  I am a rather novice at Hudson.  I am trying to do a simple Maven 'clean' on a small Java project that I know builds fine on another instance of Hudson on another server.

The stack trace from the Hudson console is below:

Thank you

---

```
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] null
hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$HeapDump
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy2.end(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuildProxy2$Filter.end(MavenBuildProxy2.java:67)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.postModule(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:922)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder$Adapter.fireLeaveModule(MavenBuilder.java:353)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder$Adapter.postBuild(MavenBuilder.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.execute(LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at hudson.maven.agent.Main.launch(Main.java:173)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder.call(MavenBuilder.java:164)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.call(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:868)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.call(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:799)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on channel failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:638)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:158)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/RemotingDiagnostics$HeapDump
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1935)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializationMethodInvoker.getMethod(SerializationMethodInvoker.java:128)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializationMethodInvoker.callWriteReplace(SerializationMethodInvoker.java:62)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:63)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:64)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.marshal(CollectionConverter.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:63)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:175)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:163)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:135)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:130)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:120)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:94)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:63)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:98)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:840)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:829)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:804)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:165)
    at hudson.model.Run.save(Run.java:1493)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.notifyModuleBuild(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:458)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild$ProxyImpl2.end(MavenBuild.java:479)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:429)
    at hudson.util.InterceptingProxy$1.invoke(InterceptingProxy.java:23)
    at $Proxy51.end(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:274)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:255)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:215)
    ... 9 more
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$HeapDump**
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    ... 55 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: version of Maven, Hudson, and Java?

Comment: Maven 2.2.1, Hudson ver. 1.393, Java 1.6.0_04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you happen to copy and paste a job (or entire hudson root) directory from your previous hudson machine to the one you installed?  The classnotfound exception is a product of hudson/xstream trying to unmarshall build configuration.

One reason this is happening is because you built the hudson on one machine with a version and then tried to copy and paste the build configuration to your local instance and run hudson with a different version.

My suggestion if thats the case is to synch up your local machine to have the same version of hudson that was previously run on.

Comment: I will try and remove all Hudson files from my test box and install the same version of Hudson as the working machine and try it again.

Comment: I'll let you know how it goes - Thanks!

Comment: So I just went back to look and its obvious now that your other machine was using hudson v 1.395 and you are using v 1.393 because 1.395 is the only current version that has the HeapDump class.  It looks  like if you upgrade to 1.395 you should be good to go

Comment: I upgraded to hudson ver 1.395 and tried building my project again and this time it was successful!  Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I have not upgraded or used any other version of hudson or copied any tasks. I am also getting this error! Checking in Hudson I see the 1.395 version is available. I did however just install the M2 maven release plugin.... Seems its stuffs up 1.394? I didn't change my job to use it yet either yet it fails.